# Regular Expression - match whole string or pattern

Tags: regex, expression

I'm doing a file search, and I want to exclude files that contain `min` in them, but I don't want to match parts of words.

so I want to exclude:

a directory named `min`
also a file named `jhkjahdf-min.txt`

But I don't want to exclude:

a file named `mint.txt`

Thank you for your help in advanced. Explanations of the regular expression you give would be a lot of extra help.

I'm using PHP's preg_match() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things called word boundaries (`\b`). They do not consume a character, but match if you go from a word character (letters, digits, underscores) to a non-word character of vice-versa. So this is a first good approximation:

```
`\bmin\b`
```

Now if you want to consider digits and underscores as word boundaries, too, it gets a bit more complicated. Then you need negative lookaheads and lookbehinds, which are not supported by all regex engines:

```
`(?<![a-zA-Z])min(?![a-zA-Z])`
```

These will also not be included in the match (if you care about it at all), but just assert that `min` is neither preceded nor followed by a letter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to anchor your regex with `\b` which means "word boundary."